# Error grabbing Heroku project using git

Tags: git, windows-7, heroku

I just cannot grab my App's source code, as per the steps documented here - http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#create_an_app

I have all steps followed correctly (as mentioned in a few other related posts).

- Valid Heroku account created.
- Logged into Heroku from command prompt.
- Uploaded a valid key
- Added the port **22** to the list of exceptions in my firewall settings.

[FYI : I'm on Windows 7]

Even after all these, I still get the following:

`ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number`

Obviously, ssh to heroku.com fails as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What `ssh -vvv heroku.com` returns?

Comment: Note: I also monitor https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts/issues/13

Comment: OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.154] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.19.85.154 port 22: Attempt to connect timed out without establishing a connection
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.156] port 22.

Comment: And I couldn't find much on the suggested link :(

Comment: That looks like some network issue...

Comment: Yes, that's what it seems like. Pointers on where to look for would be of great help!

Comment: where you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Are you still stuck? I have the same problem, and cannot find the solution. After googleing for quite a while it seems that is something related to proxies or firewalls, but neither I'm behind firewall nor connect through a proxy. There was the same issue with github, but they have the port 443 opened and it's possible to stablish ssh communication through that port.

Comment: yes, still waiting for a resolution...