# How do I push to Heroku or get info/status when it "hung up" or does not respond?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Got that error when trying to push updated app to Heroku (probably the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442101/error-grabbing-heroku-project-using-git)):

```
> git push heroku master
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I cannot connect to the API URL

```
> heroku info
 !    Unable to connect to api.heroku.com
```

Nor can I get status

```
> heroku status
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did 
not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to resp
ond. - connect(2) Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had that error on two separate occasions today.
Once when on WIFI at a cafe. Presumably port 22 blocked, though unconfirmed.
Second occurrence was at home whilst had VPN connection in to office. Likely due to some sort of firewall rule. It now works fine having disconnected from the VPN.
Conclusion is that this is a network issue.