# can't fetch me app's source code from Heroku

Tags: facebook, heroku

I want to get started with developing Facebook apps so I created one, and chose to use Heroku to host my app. when I tried to fetch me app's source code an error occurred, the following screenshot show the error:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17510525/Heroku_Trouble/Untitled.png

what's wrong and why I can't fetch the source code?
thanks a lot

edit:
the error says: "ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Comment: I just looked it up. Might be something like this? :)
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274465/ssh-connect-to-host-heroku-com-port-22-bad-file-number>

Comment: Copy the errors into your post for "searchability"

Comment: I opened port 22 in my router and the problem still exists. I'm using Windows 7 SP1 x64 and Microsoft security essentials as my security solution.