# Failing to push git to Heroku port 22: bad file number

Tags: git, heroku, ssh, git-push

After creating my rails project, pushing it into the GIT repo, was not able to push it to Heroku.
When I run the command:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get this error:

```
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Am not behind a firewall, proxy or vpn..
I have run

```
  heroku status
```

and it is working fine.

I have even made sure ssh is working fine with Git. and run

```
 ssh -vT git@github.com
```

and it run successfully

I run

```
 telnet heroku.com 22
```

and it failed

```
 connecting to heroku.com .. could not open connection to the host, on port 22:Connect failed
```

Also run and failed

```
 ssh git@heroku.com
 ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: bad file number
```

Comment: Did you check if SSH is working fine with *Heroku* too?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274465/ssh-connect-to-host-heroku-com-port-22-bad-file-number

Comment: @poke I have previously found the related questions, but they dont solve my issue.
Regarding SSHing Heroku. What command I should use exactly?

Comment: @poke , ok I have run 
ssh git@heroku.com and if failed
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: bad file number

Comment: Also run telnet heroku.com 22 and it failed
connecting to heroku.com .. could not open connection to the host, on port 22: connect failed

Comment: Can you try setting up your heroku remote using the heroku command line tool? I.e. `heroku git:remote -a <project name>`

Comment: yes I was able to run that, and it says:!    Git remote heroku already exists
actually I have already used the command "heroku create" this is why it says already exist..right?

Comment: Hmm, then I’m out of ideas. You might want to contact Heroku support.

Comment: Maybe this could help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555546/error-in-git-push-heroku-master-through-ssh-behind-proxy

Comment: What about adding the verbose flag to see details?

Answer (score 1):

The dreaded Bad file number. It's the PC LOAD LETTER of git. It's inscrutable, but almost always a bad key. Try updating your key in heroku and make sure that you are presenting the correct key when trying to connect.